# Benefit of selecting "amazonaws.com" or "api.aws" endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services

What benefits, if any, exist for selecting the host endpoint `amazonaws.com` versus `api.aws` for connecting programmatically to an AWS service?

If possible, it seems best to use amazonaws.com when you can leverage the fips-enabled endpoint (service-fips.region.amazonaws.com) but that seems to be the only difference found.

For example, the [service endpoints for Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/lambda-service.html), for the us-east-2 region include the following available endpoints:

- lambda.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
- lambda-fips.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
- lambda.us-east-2.api.aws

To ask this in another way... would you ever use `lambda.us-east-2.api.aws`, and if so, why?

Comment: `api.aws` is shortest. That would be its only benefit.

Comment: I don't remember seeing those `api.aws` endpoints in the past, so it's possible that AWS is planning to transition to the new endpoints (maybe they recently got approved for the `.aws` top-level domain). You should generally follow whatever the most recent SDK does.